# How to make Asp.Net Core Identity to work with OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

How to regenerate open id connect custom claims from asp.net core project?

I've setup manually mapping to claim type name, but some times i need to update other claim from outside of the event OnTicketRecieved, namely from controller, so at that stage i do need to regenerate somehow claims. I've set up openIdConnect in the following way:

```
        _services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = clientId;
                options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                options.Authority = $"{baseAuthorityUrl}/{tenantId}";
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString(callBackPath);
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                };

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = e =>
                    {

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTicketReceived = e =>
                    {
                        e.Principal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, e.Principal.FindFirstValue("name")));

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
```

How i can to regenerate claims from controller? 
I'm thinking just somehow override signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can update claims outside of the login event. **Update** is a controller method.

```cs
public async Task Update()
{
    AuthenticateResult authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync();

    // Make a copy of the principal so we can modify it's claims
    ClaimsPrincipal newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(User.Identity)
    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)newPrincipal.Identity;

    // Add/remove claims
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("name", "value"));
    Claim toRemove = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.Type, "claimnametoremove", StringComparison.Ordinal));
    if (toRemove != null)
        claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(toRemove);

    // If these aren't updated, calls to "User" will pull the old principal value
    HttpContext.User = newPrincipal;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newPrincipal;

    // Sign in the user with the new principal to "refresh" our logged-in user
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, newPrincipal, authenticateResult.Properties);
}
```

Comment: this is great I was banging my head against this and was did accomplish changing the claims with a very nasty code in AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>{},cookieOptions => { cookieOptions.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = async context => { context.ReplacePrincipal( }}

I've tried your method before but I was being redirected to OnTokenValidated again. The key part is I was missing AuthenticateResult authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(); and pass authenticateResult.Properties to HttpContext.SignInAsync

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add claims in controller after init login , you should make the authentication manager to use the new identity :

```
if (HttpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
{

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("userId", "1234"));
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new ClaimsPrincipal(HttpContext.User.Identity));
}
```